# Find functions which change asymptotic properties if raised to 2

Tags: functions, asymptotics, computational-complexity

Kindly give an example of positive functions f(n) and g(n) such that
            f(n) = O(g(n))

but it does not hold that 2^f(n) = O(2^g(n)).

A friend asked this question as this came in one of his exams. I have rattled my mind and couldnt figure out what this could be. It has to be some kind of log function I presume.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you don't even need logarithms. Consider $f(n) = 2n$ and $g(n) = n$.

Then, $2^{f(n)} = 2^{2n} = 4^n$ but $2^{g(n)} = 2^n$. Can you show that $2^{f(n)}$ is not $O(2^{g(n)})$?

Comment: Big O notation is tightly bound. I forgot that property. Your answer is very clever. I feel a little now!!
Thanks. :)